# Push lat/long coordinates to an array for Google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to generate map markers for a Google map based off data attributes of a set of divs. I need the array to end up looking like this:

```
var markers = [
    [51.503454,-0.119562],
    [51.499633,-0.124755]
];
```

Here's what I have tried so far:

```js
var markers = [];

$(function() {
  $('.location').each(function() {
    var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat'),
        lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');
        
    markers.push(lat,lng);
  });
  
  console.log(markers);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="location" data-lat="51.503454" data-lng="-0.119562"></div>
<div class="location" data-lat="51.499633" data-lng="-0.124755"></div>
```

How do I get the lat/lng coordinates in pairs instead of 4 separate values?

Comment: markers.push([lat,lng]);  You're trying to construct a 2d array.  Meaning each element is an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `map` method and return array with `lat`, `lng` values for each element.

```js
const markers = $('.location').map(function() {
  return [[$(this).data('lat'), $(this).data('lng')]]
}).get();

console.log(markers)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="location" data-lat="51.503454" data-lng="-0.119562"></div>
<div class="location" data-lat="51.499633" data-lng="-0.124755"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```js
var markers = [];

$(function() {
  $('.location').each(function() {
    var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat'),
        lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');
        
    markers.push([+lat,+lng]);
  });
  
  console.log(markers);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="location" data-lat="51.503454" data-lng="-0.119562"></div>
<div class="location" data-lat="51.499633" data-lng="-0.124755"></div>
```