# Pushing pairs of coordinates to a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49035097/3250782) in regards to how to achieve this in Javascript, but now I am wondering how I would go about it in PHP as well. How can I push pairs of coordinates into an array? I want the array to look like this:

```
[
    [51.503454,-0.119562],
    [51.499633,-0.124755]
]
```

And here's my attempt(this would be inside a for loop in practice instead of defining static variables for the coordinates):

```
<?php
  $locations = array();

  $lat = 51.503454;
  $lng = -0.119562;

  array_push($locations, $lat, $lng);
?>
```

Comment: `array_push($locations, [$lat, $lng]);` _or_ `$a = [$lat, $lng]; array_push($locations, $a);`

Comment: Include $lat and $lng in an array as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish that.

The shortest:

```
array_push($locations, [$lat, $lng]);
```

alternative (just a different syntax):

```
array_push($locations, array($lat, $lng));
```

easier to read/understand, but two lines:

```
$a = [$lat, $lng]; 
array_push($locations, $a);
```

without array_push:

```
$locations[] = array($lat, $lng);
```

perhaps you want that pair as an object?

```
$location = new stdClass();
$location->lat = $lat;
$location->long = $long;
$locations[] = $location;
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the various options, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I like to use short syntax for php arrays:

```
$locations[] = [$lat, $lng]
```

works as of php 5.4
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php